# Modelling confidence intervals from dependent sets of combinations

Tags: probability, statistics

There are 68 possible questions for an exam, out of the 68 they are going to pick 9 to assess. Of these 9 we only have to choose 6 to answer. 
How many of the 68 questions will I have to study to be 80% (or x%) sure I will have studied at least 6 of the 9?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please show the work you have done so far, and ask specific questions about where you get stuck. That will allow this community to help you best.

Comment: Probability problem, not confidence interval problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Clues:** You might look at this in terms of hypergeometric probabilities.

Suppose, I try to study just half of the 68 questions. Then, for me, there are 34 'good'
questions and 34 'bad' ones in the pool. Next, the examiners select 9 questions at random from among the 68.
What is the probability they pick 6 or more of my 'good' ones?

Then, from R statistical software, that's a probably of only 0.2381 that I see at least 6 good ones on the exam. Groan, more study needed.

```
sum(dhyper(6:9, 34, 68-34, 9))
[1] 0.2381416
```

[image]

What if, in an uncharacteristic burst of diligence, I study 50 out of the 68? Then the probability that I see at least 6 good ones is about 0.8202. Did I 'overstudy'? [That is, according to the criterion that the only goal to do well on the exam without (heaven forfend!) actually learning something "extra."] *Maybe,* by just a bit. Another try or two in R should settle that.

```
sum(dhyper(6:9, 50, 68-50, 9))
[1] 0.820177
```

[image]

*Note:* Perhaps you are expected to use some sort of approximation to the hypergeometric distributions, instead of getting exact values in R. Can't say, because you've
shown no context for the question.